# Invalid requirement, parse error at "'--instal'" while trying to use --install-option in requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I'm trying to install a python module using setup.py with requirements.txt. I'm installing the module using `pip install -U .` in the directory where I have a `setup.py` file.

My `setup.py` file parses the `requirements.txt` file by storing the requirements in a list of strings:

```
def get_requirements():
    root_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    requirements_file_path = os.path.join(root_path, 'requirements.txt')

    # example: `numpy >= 1.13`
    with open(requirements_file_path) as file:
        requirements = [requirement.strip() for requirement in file.readlines()]
        requirements = filter(lambda requirement: len(requirement), requirements)
        requirements = filter(lambda requirement: not requirement.startswith('-'), requirements)
        requirements = list(requirements)

    return requirements

requirements = get_requirements()
config = {'name': name, 
          'install_requires': requirements
}
setuptools.setup(**config)
```

My requirements file looks like:

```
numpy >= 1.13
pyyaml >= 3.12
matplotlib
opencv-python >= 3.2
setuptools
cython
mock
scipy
six
future
protobuf
yacs
ninja
colour
torchvision_nightly
torch_nightly --install-option="--find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu92/torch_nightly.html"
```

However, when I try to install the module with `pip install -U .`, I get the following parsing error:

```
Processing /home/my-module
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    error in my_module setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Invalid requirement, parse error at "'--instal'"

----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-req-build-rf9439sf/

Any idea on why passing `--install-option` causes a parse error?

Answer (score 2):

[Declaration of dependencies](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies) in `setuptools` has a different syntax than for [pip](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format). You have to convert one to the other automatically or manually.